# iMacros 10 macro has stopped working after upgrade from iMacros 9

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, excel, imacros

I have a macro using (Excel VBA) that goes through out invoice application.  The macro opens an invoice and extracts information on a number of different screens.  It then closes the invoice, looks for the word "reservation" on the next screen.  Once it finds "reservation, it should open the next ticket.

With IE 8 / iMacros 9, the macro did not encounter any issue.  However, recently, we were upgraded to IE 11 and iMacros 10.  When users run the macro now, they can get a "iMacros has stopped working.  A problem caused the program to stop working correctly.  Please close the program." message.

Following is the loop where the macro is looking for the word "reservation".  this appears to be the place where the error / problem occurs.

```
lCnt = 0
vpagehead = ""

Do Until InStr(1, vpagehead1, "Reservation Number") > 0 Or InStr(1, vpagehead1, "servation:") > 0 Or lCnt = 25

    IM = ""
    IM = "CODE:"
    IM = IM + "TAB T=1" + vbNewLine
    IM = IM + "TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS" + vbNewLine
    IM = IM + "FRAME NAME=ReservationDetailFrame" + vbNewLine
    IM = IM + "SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 10" + vbNewLine
    IM = IM + "TAG POS=11 TYPE=TD ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT" + vbNewLine
    IM = IM + "WAIT SECONDS=1" + vbNewLine

    iret = iim1.iimPlay(IM)

    vpagehead1 = iim1.iimGetLastExtract
    lCnt = lCnt + 1

Loop
```

Does anyone see any reason why this code would cause an issue that would cause iMacros to close?

Thanks for the help..........

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen, nobody knows a thing before to learn it. If you think there's a better approach, then you might use the comments to suggest it. But commenting just "this is a horrible approach, I want to quit my job" sounds to me really impolite to the asker who developed it and not complying with the community standards. Please go back to the old times and think that maybe you would have done the same mistakes before gaining experience.

Comment: @Chrismas007....Thanks for the comments.  I really appreciate this forum.  You are right.  You don't know what you don't know.  I come here to try and learn better ways to do things as I am mainly self-taught.  However, some of the comments are rude and impolite when someone is just trying to get some information.  I don't know why someone would waste their time in writing something that adds no value.  Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the issue is in the code. As you've said, the code works fine and so the only thing that changed is the version of the browser and iMacro.

An IE11 update possibly could have broken your macro:

http://imacros.net/microsoft-update-for-ie11-kb3025390-breaks-tag-command-in-imacros-for-ie

> If you must use iMacros with IE11, another workaround is to uninstall
>   Microsoft update KB3025390. This is a non-security related update, so
>   uninstalling it will not put IE in any greater risk.

Comment: Thanks.........We have had to uninstall that Microsoft update before using a different macro.  The funny thing is that that update keeps getting installed on our machines, even after it is removed.  Our IT department is currently looking for a solution to keep it from re-installing.  I'll check to see and make sure that it is uninstalled before running that macro again.

Comment: Once I get a chance to test it, I sure will